# Change SAS date format

Tags: date, sas

I have a date variable in **ddmmyy8**. a format such as 24/12/12, I want to change it to **ddmmyy10**. format, however, it automatically changes to 24/12/2012, which is not right, the date should be 24/12/1912.

Is there any way to tell SAS it is 1912, not 2012? or I have to minus 100 years manually?

Comment: Do you actually have a date variable? Or are you talking about converting an 8 character string into a date?

Comment: Why date should be 24/12/1912 ? Have you set the default DATE from where actually you wanted to start?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the data were from Excel as date8. format.  The date should be 1912 because they were birthdays for very old people.

Comment: You should probably fix the Excel file the to display the full date. Then you can fix it at the source.  Also probably a good idea avoid using ddmmyyyy or mmddyyyy style to display dates to avoid confusing Dec 10th and Nov 12th. If you use a display format like ddMONyyyy (DATE9.)  or yyyy/mm/dd (yymmdd10.) you won't confuse half of your audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you tell which dates should be 2012 and which should be 1912?

If your variable is really a SAS date variable then the century was already 2000, you just couldn't see it before because your were using a display format that didn't show the century.  You can use `intnx()` to adjust the value.

```
want = intnx('year',have,-100,'same');
```

If you are converting strings into dates then you might be able to use `YEARCUTOFF` option to have it interpret `12` as `1912` instead of `2012`.

```
857   %let optsave=%sysfunc(getoption(yearcutoff));
858   %put &=optsave;
OPTSAVE=1926
859   %put %sysfunc(inputn(24/12/12,ddmmyy8),date9);
24DEC2012
860   options yearcutoff=1912;
861   %put %sysfunc(inputn(24/12/12,ddmmyy8),date9);
24DEC1912
862   options yearcutoff=&optsave;
```